# group a dictionary into array of dictionary swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary that is like this:

```
var dict = ["app1.b": false, "app2.a": true, "app2.b": false, "app1.a": true, "app1.c": true, "app2.c": true]
```

I want to put them in a way so the end result would look like this:

```
[["app1.a":true,"app1.b":false,"app1.c":true],["app2.a":true,"app2.b":false,"app2.c":true]]
```

So basically put the items with same prefix into a new sub dictionary.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
var x = ["app1.b": false, "app2.a": true, "app2.b": false, "app1.a": true, "app1.c": true, "app2.c": true]

var xGrouping: [String: [String: Bool]] = [:]

for (key, value) in x {
    let prefix = key.components(separatedBy: ".").first!
    xGrouping[prefix, default: [:]][key] = value
}

var xGrouped = Array(xGrouping.values)

print(xGrouped) // [["app1.b": false, "app1.c": true, "app1.a": true], ["app2.c": true, "app2.a": true, "app2.b": false]]
```

**Note:** While I would generally recommend solving for these kind of problems on your own, I appreciate how confusing it may be for a beginner entering a new language. Hope this helps in demonstrating some of the useful behavior of Swift dictionaries.